# Scrapy Callback function not being called by Request

Tags: linux, python-2.7, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am learning Python Scrapy and I am struggling in isolating why the callback function of a request is not being executed. The workflow process scrape a website. If a item page is found, then the program test to see if the web page has an active login session. If not, then call a function to login. The issue experienced is the session expires over time and my function requires to log in after a certain period. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

The function I am trying to call is the following:

```
    def retrylogin_parse(self, response):
            #FUNCTION NOT CALLED
                self.logger.debug("Re-Login attempted for url " + self.login_url)
                return [FormRequest.from_response(response, formid= 'login-form', formdata=
   {'login[username]': self.username, 
    'login[password]': self.password}, 
    clickdata = { "type": "submit" }, callback=self.after_relogin)
    ]
```

I am trying to determine why the following function retrylogin_parse is not being called by the following line of code:

```
yield Request(self.login_url, dont_filter=True, callback=self.retrylogin_parse)
```

Here is the Code:

```
import ....

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "bot-help"
    allowed_domains = ['www.somewebsite.com']
    start_urls =["https://www.somewebsite.com/category/subcategory.html"]
    reloginCurrentUrl = ""  

    username = 'username'
    password = '1234'
    login_msg = "Welcome"
        login_url = "https://www.somewebsite.com/login/"

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('html')), callback='item_page'),
    )

    def item_page(self, response):
        image_item = Item()
        self.logger.info("item_page Called")
        str1 = response.xpath("//p[@class='welcome-msg']/text()").extract_first()

        self.logger.info("Testing if Response is still logged in")
        self.logger.debug("Message: " + str1)

        if (str1.find(self.login_msg)==-1):
            self.logger.error("Session Lost! Must Login")
            self.reloginCurrentUrl = response.url
            image_item['manu_product_url'] = response.url
            self.logger.debug("reloginCurrentUrl: " + self.reloginCurrentUrl)
            #HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO RE-LOGIN
            x = self.start_relogin(response)    
            self.logger.debug("Relogin Request completed")
            return
        else: 
            self.logger.info("Login Session is alive")


        self.logger.info("worked") 
        #SCRAPE DATA.....

        yield image_item

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        CrawlSpider.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    def start_relogin(self, response):
        self.logger.debug("start_relogin function called")
        x = response.url
        self.logger.debug("Login Url: " + self.login_url)
        yield Request(self.login_url, dont_filter=True, callback=self.retrylogin_parse)

    def retrylogin_parse(self, response):
    #FUNCTION NOT CALLED
        self.logger.debug("Re-Login attempted for url " + self.login_url)
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response, formid= 'login-form', formdata={'login[username]': self.username, 'login[password]': self.password}, clickdata = { "type": "submit" }, callback=self.after_relogin)]  

    def after_relogin(self, response):
        self.logger.info("Post Re-Login Attempted")
        str1 = response.xpath("//p[@class='welcome-msg']/text()").extract_first()

        if (str1.find(self.login_msg) == -1):
            self.logger.info("Re-Login failed")
                return
        else:
            self.logger.info("Re-Login successful will conitnue to parse")
            return [Request(url=self.reloginCurrentUrl)]
```

Here is the Debug Output:

```
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.somewebsite.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-10-30 23:49:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.somewebsite.com/category/subcategory.html> (referer: None)
2018-10-30 23:49:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.somewebsite.com/category/abc-46467.html> (referer: https://www.somewebsite.com/category/subcategory.html)
2018-10-30 23:49:35 [foagroupbot-help] INFO: item_page Called
2018-10-30 23:49:35 [foagroupbot-help] INFO: Testing if Response is still logged in
2018-10-30 23:49:35 [foagroupbot-help] DEBUG: Message: Login Please!
2018-10-30 23:49:35 [foagroupbot-help] ERROR: Session Lost! Must Login
2018-10-30 23:49:35 [foagroupbot-help] DEBUG: reloginCurrentUrl: https://www.somewebsite.com/category/abc-46467.html
2018-10-30 23:49:35 [foagroupbot-help] DEBUG: Relogin Request completed
```

Comment: try replace `x = self.start_relogin(response)` with `yield self.start_relogin(response)` , i guess the start_relogin function has a yield expression, which will never run if has no trigger to it

Comment: @wllbll - Thank you so much for responding. I made the changes you recommended however it did not work. I got the following error:  ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'generator'

Comment: sorry, my fault , you should use `yield from self.start_relogin(response)`

Comment: @wllbll- Hi the code is running on python 2.7 therefore the syntax 'yield from' therefore i wrote instead the following:    'for element in self.start_relogin(response): yield element'

Comment: @wllbll - The result did not work. The function retrylogin_parse did not fire. Sorry for the bad formatting in text.